# Quartz.NET - edit/delete job page

Tags: c#, gridview, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET for a C# Windows Service I am creating. I want the administrators to be able to access a webpage that displays all jobs and associated triggers in a gridview so they can update or delete the jobs.

The issue I have is a lot of data I want to be displayed/editable is stored in the `JOB_DATA` field, which is a binary image field, so cannot be accessed easily using the gridview. How do I go about getting the `JobDetail` information for each row, and getting the data map for the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create any Class and Put it in the JobDataMap and Just extract it again when using a specific job:

```
class test
{
  public string path;
}
JobDataMap newJobDataMap = new JobDataMap();

newJobDataMap.Put("ClassvariableNameToUseToGetTheInformationAtALaterStage",test);

JobDetail testDetail = new JobDetail(Job_Name, typeof(test)) { JobDataMap = newJobDataMap };
```

Then at a later stage u can get the Job Detail and retreive the information as below:

```
JobDataMap map = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

testjobDetail jobDetailToUse =
 (testjobDetail )map.Get("ClassvariableNameToUseToGetTheInformationAtALaterStage");
```